# CSS grid columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this code:

```
.four-items-across-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:0px 80% 1fr; 
}
```

I was wondering when I resize the page at width of `800px` for example the `1fr` column can get another row without media query?

If yes, how?

Comment: how you will do it with media query? saying *1fr in the next row* isn't very clear

Comment: jquery checking how big your width is and according to the width change your grid to get multiple rows?

Comment: Oh well im new with css grid and i have no idea how to solve this ! In the left 80% there are some products and 1fr (20%) is an cart. I want that cart to go bottom when the screen is to small!

Answer (score 1):

I think flexbox is more suitable for this

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height:100px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100%;
}
.container > div:first-child{
  flex:1 1 80%;
  background:red;
}
.container > div:last-child{
  flex:1 1 20%;
  background:blue;
  min-width:100px; /*adjust this like you want*/
}

/*to illustrate*/
.container:hover {
  width:40%;
  transition:1s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```